# Different Urls for Spring Boot Conrtoller in Swagger Ui

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

##### About the problem

I have several controls with different endpoints.
These are all currently listed at localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html.
I would like each controller to be accessible under its own url.

##### Question

Is there any way this can be implemented?
Does anyone already have experience with this?

It is about a university project.

We are using Spring boot with mave.

This is our current configuration, as I understood it from the documentation, each controller should have its own URL, but this is not the case.

##### Current config

Our spring version is `3.0.5`

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
    @Bean
    public List<GroupedOpenApi> api() {
        List<String[]> controllerInfos = ControllerClassServiceImpl.getPackageNamesAndApiUris();
        List<GroupedOpenApi> groups = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String[] controllerInfo: controllerInfos ){
            groups.add(GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group(controlerInfos[0])
                .pathsToMatch("/" + controlerInfos[1] + "/**")
                .build());
            return groups;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI myOpenApi() {
        Server devServer = new Server();
        devServer.setUrl(devUrl);
        devServer.setDescription("Server URL in Development environment");

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setName("Organization Management");
        contact.setUrl("https://www.example.com");

        Info info = new Info()
            .title("Example API")
            .version("1.0")
            .contact(contact)
            .description("This API exposes endpoints to the university project.");

        return new OpenAPI().info(info).servers(List.of(devServer));
    }
```

The result should be that each controller has its own url.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable the swagger configuration via yaml, extend the controller from OpenApiWebMvcResource and write the necessary endpoints, and provide the necessary documents for each

I think it must work